# Insert dictionary to list of dictionary python

Tags: python

How can I insert a dictionary to list of dictionary?

newDict = `[{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}]`

myData = `[{'title': 'Bar', 'barname': 'Archer}, {'title': 'Bar', 'barname': 'Archer}]`

output:

`[{'id': 1, 'title': 'Bar', 'barname': 'Archer}, {'id': 2, 'title': 'Bar', 'barname': 'Archer'}]`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip` and dictionary unpacking:

```
[{**dict_1, **dict_2} for dict_1, dict_2 in zip(newDict, myData)]

[{'id': 1, 'title': 'Bar', 'barname': 'Archer'},
 {'id': 2, 'title': 'Bar', 'barname': 'Archer'}]
```

(or `dict_1 | dict_2` starting from Python 3.9)

---

In case the ids in `newDict` are meant to index the elements of `myData` (1-based):

```
[{**id_select, **myData[id_select["id"] - 1]} for id_select in newDict]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using loops you can do it this way:

```
for n in range(min(len(newDict),len(myData))):
    new,my=newDict[n],myData[n]
    for key in my:
        new[key] = my[key]
```

After this your desired output==newDict. You should also think of how you want to deal with duplicate keys if that's a possibility.